# Interview Offer

Tags: interviewing

I am currently searching and received an invitation to interview with a company that would require at least an hour plus commute. The company does have a location closer to my home. How should I respond?

Comment: Pls. be aware that you seem to have submitted this question twice. Here is the other one: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/173103/interview-offer I suggest that you leave up this question, and delete the linked duplicate one.

Comment: What are your goals and what are you willing to accept?  The answer is likely different if you'd be willing to commute if it wasn't possible to work at the closer location, if you'd only accept a position at the closer location, or if you were open to a compromise where you worked out of the closer location and visited the one an hour away weekly/ monthly/ etc.

Comment: @Alice as others have mentioned there as an exact duplicate of the question submitted (I 'm guessing just an accident), as this version already had an answer posted I've elected to delete the other one

Answer (score 2):

If this is a just once commute, I suggest you to go ahead and have the interview. During it, ask about the possibility to work at the closer location, but without putting too much emphasis (don't let them think that it's a dealbreaker condition, even if it is).

You can reevaluate after the interview whether to accept or refuse an offer.

Comment: Currently you would also enquire about remote working.